# Export-PSSession not exporting any cmdlets

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, powershell-5.0

I'm trying to export a remote Microsoft Exchange session using Export-PSSession however when I do this none of the Exchange specific cmdlets have been imported when I import the module, only the Exchange specific counters work. This is what I have so far:

```
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://my.exchange.server.name.and.domain/PowerShell/ -Authentication Kerberos -Credential administrator
Export-PSSession -Session $Session -OutputModule ExchangeCmdlets -CommandType All -CommandName * -AllowClobber -Force
Import-Module -name ExchangeCmdlets
Get-ExchangeServer
```

I feel like I'm close but missing something.

Comment: I've always done `Import-PSSession` to get the cmdlets from the remote server imported into the local session.

Comment: I have also been doing this however I've notice better performance using this however I can't get it working like Import-PSSession

Comment: Don't the exchange management tools provide a PowerShell module / snap-in for administration? I've never installed them myself... I always just import the session.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `-PSSession` parameter in `Import-Module` cmdlet.

```
Import-Module -PSSession $Session
```